# Python - How to generate a binning index for a list?

Tags: python, binning

I have a 10 bins:

```
    bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I have a list of 25 values:

```
    values = [10,0,0,14,14,123,235,0,0,0,0,0,12,12,1235,23,234,15,15,23,136,34,34,37,45]
```

I want to bin the values sequentially into the bins so each value is grouped into its bin:

`binnedValues = [[10,0],[0,14,14],[123,235],[0,0,0],[0,0],[12,12,1235],[23,234],[15,15,23],[136,34,34],[37,45]]`

As you can see, the number of values in the bin is not always the same, (as `len(values) != len(bins)`)

Also, I have lots of different values lists that are all different sizes. So I need to do this a number of times for the same number of bins, but different lengths of values lists. The above is an example - the real bin size is 10k, and the real len(values) is from ~10k to ~750k..

Is there a way to do this consistently? I need to maintain the order of the values, but split the values list evenly so there is a 'fair' and 'even' number of the values range distributed to each of the bins.

I think I can use numpy.digitize, but having had a look, I can't see how to generate the 'binned' list

Comment: What do you mean by binning the values sequentially? Can you clarify? `binnedValues`'s placement looks a bit arbitrary, except that it it's in the same order as the original list.

Comment: The placement is arbitary, as I was trying to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve. If len(values)= 20, then each bin would have 2 values. If len(values) = 30, then each bin would have 3 values. I'm trying to figure out how to 'evenly' distribute values into bins when say len(values) = 27 (so 7 bins would have 3 values, and 3 would have 2) - how can I evenly distribute the differently sized bins into the bin range... better?

Comment: What is your expected output if you had 26 items?

Comment: 6 bins would have 3 values, and 4 would have 2. The bins with 2 associated values would be even spread throughout the bin ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to split the list into lists of alternating size between 2 and 3 elements? That's doable, then.

```
from itertools import cycle

values = [10,0,0,14,14,123,235,0,0,0,0,0,12,12,1235,23,234,15,15,23,136,34,34,37,45]
splits = cycle([2,3])
bins = []
count = 0

while count < len(values):
    splitby = splits.next()
    bins.append(values[count:count+splitby])
    count += splitby

print bins
```

**Edit:**

Ah, I see what you're requesting... sort of. Something more like:

from itertools import cycle
from math import floor, ceil

```
values = [10,0,0,14,14,123,235,0,0,0,0,0,12,12,1235,23,234,15,15,23,136,34,34,37,45]
number_bins = 10
bins_lower = int(floor(len(values) / float(number_bins)))
bins_upper = int(ceil(len(values) / float(number_bins)))

splits = cycle([bins_lower, bins_upper])
bins = []
count = 0

while count < len(values):
    splitby = splits.next()
    bins.append(values[count:count+splitby])
    count += splitby

print bins
```

If you want to more variety in bin size, you can add more numbers to `splits`

**Edit 2:**

Ashwin's way, which is more concise without being harder to understand.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
from math import floor, ceil

values = [10,0,0,14,14,123,235,0,0,0,0,0,12,12,1235,23,234,15,15,23,136,34,34,37,45]
number_bins = 10
bins_lower = int(floor(len(values) / float(number_bins)))
bins_upper = int(ceil(len(values) / float(number_bins)))

splits = cycle([bins_lower, bins_upper])

it = iter(values)
bins = [list(islice(it,next(splits))) for _ in range(10)] 
print bins
```

Comment: Thats just an example - the real bin size is 10k, and the real len(values) is from ~10k to ~750k... I appreciate your example though, sorry if I wasted your time through being unclear! I will edit the main post.

Comment: Wow! thats awesome. How did you do that! (and so fast!)

Comment: how about `[list(islice(it,next(splits))) for _ in range(10)]`, where `it` is `iter(values)`.

Comment: Fancy guy, @AshwiniChaudhary. I'm not that familiar with itertools, but that is nice.

Comment: Does this give the expected output when `splits = cycle([3, 4])`?

Comment: @sberry: if by expected output, you mean spitting out alternating lists of length 3 and 4, then yes.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is there a reason to do `it=iter(values)`, when you can just give `values` directly to `islice`? Won't `islice` work incrementally anyway, since it's in `itertools`?

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that they were cycling like that.